# getallheaders() missing when using nginx and php

Tags: php, nginx

I am also having this issue on an EC2 instance with the latest Amazon Linux build. The `getallheaders()` function doesn't work when on `nginx`. All of the posted replacements for `getallheaders()` only get values from `$_SERVER`. The problem is that the headers I need are not there.

I am testing my original implementation using Postman (a Chrome App). It has a Headers tab and a Body tab. I can find the entries in the Body tab in the `$_POST` array. The entries in the Headers tab are not there or in any of the other global arrays.

The code I'm working on is a web service for an app (that I don't control), so I can't change the nature of the calls.

Here are the Headers that I get when calling `getallheaders()` running on Apache (I removed a few for clarity):

```
Array
(
    [Host] => api.dashforhealth.com
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Cache-Control] => no-cache
    [Origin] => chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
    [api_key] => this-is-not-the-real-api-key
    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [Postman-Token] => 76069288-e74e-3791-eb42-f166454d8822
    [auth_key] => this-is-not-the-real-auth-key
    [Accept] => */*
)
```

The two I'm interested in are `api_key` and `auth_key`. How can I get these headers when running in `nginx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a setting for this:  underscores_in_headers

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers

Comment: That solves the problem. I added `underscores_in_headers on;` to the nginx config file for that domain and I can get the headers I need from `$_SERVER`.